# How to require namespaced models in Mocha testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a complex structured backbone application which is not tested yet.

I've choosen Mocha+Chai as testing suite but facing problems when it comes to include some modules.

All models are namespaced as,

```
Model.Service = Backbone.Model.extend({
...
...

Model.Partner = Backbone.Model.extend({
...
...
etc.
```

Model namespace itself declared  as

```
//global_vars.js
var GLOBAL = window;
...
GLOBAL.Model            = {};
```

When I tried to write a simple test like

```
'use strict';
require ('mocha');    

var Service =  require ('../../client/model/Service.js')
var expect = require ('chai').expect;

describe('Testing Service model', function(){
        it('should create global variable for Service', function(){
            expect(Service).to.be.exist;
        });
    });
```

It threw error,

```
Model.Service = Backbone.Model.extend({
^

ReferenceError: Model is not defined
```

The added,

```
require('../../client/global_vars.js');
```

before `Service` declaration, but this time got

```
var GLOBAL = window;
             ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

I'm actually not familiar with javascript mvc structure, node module inclusion, etc. and really do not know how to dig in.

Directory structure if needed

```
$ tree source/client/
source/client/
├── Application.js 
├── collection
│   ├── I18n.js
│   ├── Invoice.js
│   └── Service.js
├── controller
│   ├── hardware
│   │   └── Cash.js
│   ├── Hardware.js
│   ├── I18n.js
│   ├── Remote.js
│   └── ServiceManager.js
├── draft.js
├── global_vars.js
├── lib
│   ├── access_deep_object.js
│   ├── backbone.validation.async.js
│   ├── color_transition.js
│   ├── dom_utils.js
│   ├── error.js
│   ├── jquery.form.serialize_object.js
│   ├── number_utils.js
│   ├── path.js
│   ├── promise_core.js
│   ├── remove_regexp_specials.js
│   ├── stringTemplate.js
│   ├── string_utils.js
│   └── the_key.js
├── model
│   ├── Cacheable.js
│   ├── Controller.js
│   ├── Countdown.js
│   ├── Device.js
│   ├── hardware
│   │   ├── BillAcceptor.js
│   │   ├── CashDispenser.js
│   │   ├── IDReader.js
│   │   ├── SmartCoin.js
│   │   └── ThermalPrinter.js
│   ├── I18n.js
│   ├── Invoice.js
│   ├── Object.js
│   ├── Partner.js
│   ├── Performer.js
│   ├── ServerSideEvent.js
│   ├── Service.js
│   ├── Session.js
│   ├── Storage.js
│   └── Transaction.js
├── start.js
├── template
................ 
├── vars.js
├── vendor
................
└── view
    ├── AppView.js
    ├── Console.js
    ├── ModalWindow.js
    ├── page
    │   ├── about.js
    │   ├── articles
    │   │   ├── list.js
    │   │   └── tiles.js
    │   ├── checkout
    │   │   ├── card.js
    │   │   └── cash.js
    │   ├── custom
    │   │   └── mobile_operator
    │   │       ├── auth.js
    │   │       └── packages.js
    │   ├── exception
    │   │   ├── connection.js
    │   │   ├── dataloss.js
    │   │   ├── emergency.js
    │   │   └── transaction.js
    │   ├── gallery.js
    │   ├── input
    │   │   ├── phone.js
    │   │   └── text.js
    │   ├── select
    │   │   └── packages.js
    │   ├── single_invoice.js
    │   ├── start.js
    │   ├── test
    │   │   ├── hardware.js
    │   │   └── payment.js
    │   └── thankyou.js
    ├── Page.js
    ├── Prototype.js
    └── Registration.js

50 directories, 127 files
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up your test environment correctly? I have a separate directory for my tests:

```
├── Test
|    ├── js
|    |    ├── spec
|    |       ├── myModel.spec.js
|    ├── test.html
```

Then, in the test.html, you include your dependencies

```
  ...
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="mocha"></div>
      <!-- JavaScript Test Libraries -->
      <script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
      <script src="../node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>
      <script src="../node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon.js"></script>
      <!-- JavaScript Core Libraries -->
      <script src="../node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
      <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../node_modules/backbone/backbone-min.js"></script>
      <!-- JavaScript Application Libraries -->
      <script src="../app/js/namespace.js"></script>
      <script src="../app/js/templates/templates.js"></script>
      <script src="../app/js/models/myModel.js"></script>
      <script src="../app/js/views/myView.js"></script>
      <!-- set up mocha and chai -->
      <script>
          var expect = chai.expect;
          mocha.setup('bdd');

          window.onload = function(){
              mocha.run();
          };
      </script>

      <!-- include our specs -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/spec/namespace.spec.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/spec/myModel.spec.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/spec/myView.spec.js"></script>

...
<div id="mocha"></div>
<div id="fixtures" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

Then you write your tests in the [yourModel].spec.js file like this. In this example it is myModel.spec.js

```
describe("App.Models.Station", function () {
    it("Model creation is OK", function () {
        var model = new App.Models.Station();
        expect(model).to.be.ok;
    });
});
```

Then open your browser and open test.html to run your tests. Also check that all relative paths are correct.

Comment: i'm running tests on terminal. let me try your last snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are trying to run code that needs the global space to be named `window` in an environment that does not have a global space named `window`. In Node, the global space is `global`. At a minimum you'd need something like this:

```
var GLOBAL =  typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : global;
```

I would put the whole shebang in an IIFE. Otherwise, you are defining a variable named `GLOBAL` on whatever global space exists. So:

```
(function () {
  var GLOBAL =  typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : global;
  GLOBAL.Model = {};
  // etc...
}());
```

This will solve your immediate hurdle. This being said, depending on the type of test you run you may need to have a `window` that is as close as possible to an actual DOM `Window` object. If so, you can use JSDom. There are dozens of questions about how to use it on SO. I've run thousands of tests over the years my advice is to use JSDom only if you absolutely need it. Don't get me wrong, JSDom is great and absolutely necessary for some tests but it has overhead.